# Как найти путь бинарного файла?

Tags: c++, winapi

Исполняемое приложение подключает плагин. Как внутри этого плагина узнать абсолютный путь по которому он лежит?

Comment: Если плагин это DLL, то ищи по слову `GetModuleFileNameW`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого в WinAPI есть функция [GetModuleFileName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamew). С ней однако нужно обратить внимание на важный момент - в первом аргументе указывается хэндл модуля, для которого надо получить путь. Так вот, если указать там `NULL`, то вернется путь к .exe программы, а не к .dll плагина. Поэтому плагин должен сохранять свой хэндл, который ему передается как аргумент `DllMain`, и использовать его для вызова `GetModuleFileName`.