# Как найти путь до плагина внутри плагина (.dll .so)?

Tags: c++, linux

```
// узнаем абсолютный путь до подключаемой библиотеки
#ifdef IS_WINDOWS

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
    DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    WCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameW(hinstDLL, szPath, MAX_PATH);
}

#else
???
#endif
```

Comment: На линуксе есть dladdr, но зачем?

Comment: мне надо знать где валяется эта либа. Исполняемый файл об этом знает... но. мне не надо чтобы исполняемый файл передавал путь до этой либы внутрь этой либы.

Comment: Если исполняемый файл об этом знает, то пусть передает этот путь в либу...

Comment: я бы не хотел передавать путь. Должно же быть решение

Comment: Решение я уже привел. Но зачем так делать - непонятно. Да и зачем внутри библиотеки может понадобится путь к ней - тоже.

Comment: Судя по этому вопросу, вы приняли к сведению мой ответ на другой [ваш вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/946108/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0) четыре дня назад. Мне вот интересно - а чем вас тогда мой ответ не устраивает, что вы его не хотите принимать?